# Why can't concept refinement use the terse syntax

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

When refining concepts, the way it is consistently done in the standard is to fully write out the concept being refined. For instance, in [[concepts.integral]](http://eel.is/c++draft/concepts.integral), `SignedIntegral` refines `Integral` like so:

```
template<class T>
  concept Integral = is_integral_v<T>;
template<class T>
  concept SignedIntegral = Integral<T> && is_signed_v<T>;
```

Why can't the refined concept be written as:

```
template<Integral T>
  concept SignedIntegral2 = is_signed_v<T>;
```

`SignedIntegral2` seems to have the same obvious meaning of `SignedIntegral`, but it doesn't even compile on clang. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The declaration of `SignedIntegral2` is ill-formed because of [[temp.concept]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#concept-4):

> A concept shall not have associated constraints.

And it's important to understand the reason for this. Concepts are basically predicates. Their job is to take a series of arguments (most commonly, a series of types) and say whether the concept is satisfied or not. But consider what answer these two different implementations would give:

- `SignedIntegral<int32_t>` is `true`
- `SignedIntegral<uint32_t>` is `false`
- `SignedIntegral<string>` is `false`

But:

- `SignedIntegral2<int32_t>` is `true`
- `SignedIntegral2<uint32_t>` is `false`
- `SignedIntegral2<string>` is... undefined

The whole point of concepts is to constrain. The proposed alternative, terse declaration in `SignedIntegral2` *constrains* the type parameter `T` to be `Integral`. Since `string` does not satisfy `Integral`, we cannot even ask the question of if it's a `SignedIntegral2`.

Put a different way, `SignedIntegral` is a total function but `SignedIntegral2` is a partial function that is only defined on `Integral` types. This might be more clear if we write both to actually be functions:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool SignedIntegral() { return Integral<T> && is_signed_v<T>; }

template <Integral T>
constexpr bool SignedIntegral2() { return is_signed_v<T>; }
```

It is important that concepts always be total functions, which is why associated constraints are disallowed.

---

Note that it is surely possible as an extension to treat "undefined" as `false` for the purposes of concepts satisfaction, but this would add extra wrinkles to the subsumption rules and it's surely non-trivial implementation complexity. It's certainly possible that some future standard might allow them. My crystal ball is currently at the shop, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I think I understand your point, but isn't [`is_signed_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) defined as `false` for non-arithmetic types rather than being 'undefined'?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Yes, but `SignedIntegral2<string>` is undefined because there is no valid instantiation for `SignedIntegral2` with a non-integral type. That's what it means when a template constraint fails. Now, if there were a separate definition of `SignedIntegral2` that was unconstrained, then that could be instantiated. And technically, it would not "undefined"; it would be ill-formed

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't notice the template parameter was `Integral T` rather than `typename T`. Silly me. :/

Comment: This is really two separate questions. "Why can't we have constrained concepts" and "why can't we define constraints on concepts to mean conjunction instead".

Comment: This question will see a lot of traffic in the following years. The second version looks undoubtedly natural for anyone new to concepts.