# Using a concept in another concept's 'requires' clause

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a fairly simple example that I'm struggling with. I'd like to use an already-defined concept in another concept's `requires` clause - something like this, except actually working:

```
template<typename T>
concept Any = true;

template<typename T>
concept UsesAnyA = requires(T t, Any auto a) {
  t(a);
};
```

I've also tried defining `UsesAny` like this, to no further avail:

```
template<typename T, Any A>
concept UsesAnyB = requires(T t, A a) {
  t(a);
};
```

From a conceptual (...sorry) angle it feels like this should be possible. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: "*From a conceptual (...sorry) angle it feels like this should be possible.*" Unfortunately, this is not possible. How can the compiler generate *all* types that satisfy `Any`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 - the first concept (Any) I just defined as simply as possible, for the purposes of this example. In real life it is more specified than that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use concept to detect whether the type `T` can accept any parameter that satisfies `Any`? But since `Any` is *not* a type, if you don't pass a *specific* type to `T`, the compiler will not help you generate a type that satisfies `Any`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I'd like C++ to use its usual type inference, but, if I pass an object to `UsesAny::operator()` that does not meet the requirements for the `Any` concept, I'd like it to tell me at compile time that's an error.

Comment: Then just simply constrain it like `UsesAny::operator()(Any auto)`.

Comment: What do you mean, to no further avail? `UsesAnyB` looks fine.

Comment: @Barry I get this error from UsesAnyB: `a concept cannot be constrained`

Comment: @ChrisJHarris Oh right, I forgot about that rule. [Even answered that question once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53684992/2069064).

Comment: @Barry - your answer is actually pretty helpful - "It is important that concepts always be total functions" - that's a nice simple way to phrase it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably need to do something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Any = true;

template <typename T, typename A>
concept UsesAny = Any<A> and requires (T t, A a) {
  t(a);
};
```

A concept needs each of the complete types involved in order to test its constraint, but at the point you evaluate it, you should already have the complete types available to test with.

I realize checking `Any<A>` in this example is redundant, but I'm assuming your actual concept is not trivial, and this demonstrates how to use it to constrain your dependent concept.

Here are the three different ways you can constrain a template with `UsesAny`:

```cpp
template <typename A>
auto f(A a, UsesAny<A> auto t) { t(a); }

template <typename A, UsesAny<A> T>
auto f(A a, T t) { t(a); }

template <typename A, typename T>
requires UsesAny<T, A>
auto f(A a, T t) { t(a); }
```

each of these forms are equivalent.